# Firefox back button behaviour on single page application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on SSO page, In there there is function that navigated to another domain single page application which uses angularjs. If users decide to go back, Firefox back button, doesn't navigating to that page.

Comment: Maybe the single page application does some redirecting immediately if you enter the page?

Comment: yeah, Maybe. But browser go back to history when press back button right. I'm thinking it's deadlock certain situation.

Comment: Then what do you expect the users here to do? We cannot investigate any of that stuff

Comment: I want to go back to history. In this case, chrome, safari works fine. But firefox make me trapped on second application page. I cannot go back any of previous history.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started... I disable them in my app, but once they're trapped, you can do with the keypresses what you will.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // Stop enter/backspace doing their browser defaults.
    if (typeof window.event != 'undefined') { // IE
        document.onkeydown = function() {
            var t=event.srcElement.type;
            var kc=event.keyCode;
            return ((kc != 8 && kc != 13) || ( t == 'text' &&  kc != 13 ) || (t == 'textarea') || ( t == 'password' ) || ( t == 'search' ) || ( t == 'submit' &&  kc == 13));
        }
    } else {
        document.onkeypress = function(e) { // FireFox/Others
            var kc=e.keyCode;
            if ((kc != 8 && kc != 13) || ( t == 'text' &&  kc != 13 ) || (t == 'textarea') || ( t == 'password' ) || ( t == 'search' ) || ( t == 'submit' &&  kc == 13)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('Sorry Backspace/Enter is not allowed here'); // Demo code
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```